# Dart/Flutter : List of days in a date range

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to retrieve a list of days from a date range. The user selects the start date and the end date and it calculates the days in between (start and end included).

I tried to use a for loop as follow:

```dart
List<DateTime> calculateDaysInterval(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {
    List<DateTime> days = [];
    for (DateTime d = startDate;
        d.isBefore(endDate);
        d.add(Duration(days: 1))) {
      days.add(d);
    }
    return days;
  }
```

but it doesn't work and it freezes the app.
Do you guys have any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `var start = DateTime.now();
  var end = DateTime.now().add(Duration(hours: 100));
  var list = [];
  while (start.isBefore(end)) {
    list.add(start);
    start = start.add(Duration(days: 1));
  }
  print(list);`

Answer (score 23):

How about:

```
final daysToGenerate = end.difference(start).inDays;
days = List.generate(daysToGenerate, (i) => DateTime(start.year, start.month, start.day + (i)));
```

Comment: I like this approach but would use the DateTime add function rather than adding to the days directly to avoid issues between months/years `List<DateTime> days = List.generate(daysToGenerate, (i) => start.add(Duration(days: i)))`

Comment: @alexbhandari If anything Rob's answer is better because with Dart durations, a day is just 24 hours, whereas in reality, days can sometimes be 23 or 25 hours

Comment: This solution does not work for two next days  
    ```//given
    var dateTimeStart = DateTime(2020, 1, 1);
    var dateTimeEnd = DateTime(2020, 1, 2);

    //when
    var range = DateTimeRange(start: dateTimeStart, end: dateTimeEnd);
    List<DateTime> rangeList = range.calculateDaysInterval();

    //then
    List<DateTime> expectedList = [dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd];
    expect(rangeList.length, expectedList.length);```

Answer (score 9):

I might have found a solution.
It doesn't look that great but it gets the job done.

```dart
List<DateTime> calculateDaysInterval(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {
    List<DateTime> days = [];
    for (int i = 0; i <= endDate.difference(startDate).inDays; i++) {
      days.add(startDate.add(Duration(days: i)));
    }
    return days;
  }
```

If you guys have a better approach let me know.

Comment: This may work in unexpected ways if the dates are in a locale with day light savings. For example the following in PST timezone:  `var date = new DateTime(2020, 3, 7, 23, 59); debugPrint(date.add(Duration(days: 1)).toString());` will print `flutter: 2020-03-09 00:59:00.000` and  `var date = new DateTime(2020, 11, 1, 23, 59); debugPrint(date.add(Duration(days: 1)).toString());` will print `flutter: 2020-11-02 23:59:00.000`, which may be what you want, but often will not be.

Comment: Just to clarify, because of daylight savings adding a day to the first DateTime object, which has `date.day == 7`, results in `date.day == 9` because of the time change and in the second example `date.day == 2` even after adding `Duration(days: 1)`

Answer (score 2):

Referencing the original question and trying to keep the code as similar as possible, the reason that the code freezes your app is because the `add` function inside of your for loop does not work inplace and instead returns a new `DateTime` as shown here:[image: information about DateTime function add]
So, in order to fix your code, all you would need to do is change the final part of the for loop to `d = d.add(const Duration(days: 1))`

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best efficient (Actually Definitely isn't efficient) but if you must absolutely get the exact number of days regardless, considering the Daylight saving, this would work.

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2020, 3, 2);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2020, 3, 10);
List<DateTime> days = [];
DateTime tmp = DateTime(startDate.year, startDate.month, startDate.day, 12);
while(DateTime(tmp.year, tmp.month, tmp.day) != endDate){
  days.add(DateTime(tmp.year, tmp.month, tmp.day));
  tmp = tmp.add(new Duration(days: 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use a for loop or traverse through date range if you implement Iterable in a function or class member (yet you can find a List object) like this,

```
Class DateFormatter { 
  .....
  ....

   static Iterable<DateTime> EachDay(DateTimeRange dateRange) {
     List<DateTime> iterated = [];
    
     for (var day = dateRange.start.day; day <= dateRange.end.day; day++) {
       iterated.add(dateRange.start.add(Duration(days: day)));
     }
     return iterated;
   }
}
```

and a 'for' loop like,

```
for (DateTime cDate in DateFormatter.EachDay(dateRange)) {
  print(cDate.toString());
}
```

There's a way to implement iterator as well and all these leaves minimal footprint on the code.
with iterator,

```
var theITerator = DateFormatter.EachDay(dateRange).iterator;
    theITerator.moveNext();
```