# How to get all events in a month using table_calendar in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, backend

I have built a calendar with user's appointments using table_calendar in flutter. In my current code, I can only return all appointments of the user. Now, I am trying to fetch all appointments within a same month only and display them below the calendar. That is to say, when I swap the month on the calendar, I should  **only** see a list of appointments within the month I am currently looking at.

Currently, I am fetching all appointment records of the user from backend. To achieve my goal, which way will be easier:

*by defining the 'change month button' with date info of the first day of that month and using it to select corresponding data in backend*

**OR**

*still retrieving all appointment records and filter them in frontend somehow?*

Can anyone please help me achieving my goal with specific solution?

(As shown in my current output below, while I am at October, I am still seeing the appointment in June).
[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb7i0.jpg)

**Frontend code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';
import 'package:frontend/util/authentication.dart';
import 'package:frontend/util/serverDetails.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:frontend/components/appointment.dart';
import 'package:frontend/screens/appointmentdetail.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:frontend/main.dart';
import 'package:frontend/screens/appointmentlist.dart';

class Appointments extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppointmentsState createState() => _AppointmentsState();
}

class _AppointmentsState extends State<Appointments>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  var _calendarController;
  Map<DateTime, List> _events;
  List<Appointment> _samemonthevents = List<Appointment>();
  AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _events = Map<DateTime, List>();
    _calendarController = CalendarController();

    getSameMonthAppointments();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    );
    _animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _calendarController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  getSameMonthAppointments() async {
    String currentToken = await Authentication.getCurrentToken();
    print(currentToken);
    if (currentToken == null) {
      print('bouncing');
      Authentication.bounceUser(context);
    } else {
      String auth = "Bearer " + currentToken;
      String url = ServerDetails.ip +
          ':' +
          ServerDetails.port +
          ServerDetails.api +
          'me/appointments';
      print(url);
      Map<String, String> headers = {"Authorization": auth};
      print(headers);
      var jsonResponse = null;
      var response = await http.get(url, headers: headers);
      print(response.body);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print("200" + response.body);
        jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
        if (jsonResponse != null) {
          setState(() {
            for (var doc in jsonResponse) {
              _samemonthevents.add(Appointment.fromJson(doc));
            }
          });
        }
      } else {
        print(response.body);
      }
    }
  }

  void _onVisibleDaysChanged(
      DateTime first, DateTime last, CalendarFormat format) {
    print('CALLBACK: _onVisibleDaysChanged');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(60.0),
          child: AppBar(
            leading: new IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                color: Colors.black,
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {});
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainPage()));
                }),
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text("Appointment", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            brightness: Brightness.light,
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
//          backgroundColor: Color(0x44000000),
            elevation: 0.5,
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                color: Colors.black,
                icon: Icon(Icons.list),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {});
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => AppointmentList()));
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: new Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return new Column(children: <Widget>[
            _buildTableCalendarWithBuilders(),
            const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            //_buildEventList()
            //_buildsameMonthEventList()
            Expanded(child: _buildsameMonthEventList()),
          ]);
        }));
  }

  // More advanced TableCalendar configuration (using Builders & Styles)
  Widget _buildTableCalendarWithBuilders() {
    return TableCalendar(
      calendarController: _calendarController,
      events: _events,
      //holidays: _holidays,
      initialCalendarFormat: CalendarFormat.month,
      formatAnimation: FormatAnimation.slide,
      startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.sunday,
      availableGestures: AvailableGestures.all,
      availableCalendarFormats: const {CalendarFormat.month: ''},
      calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
        outsideDaysVisible: false,
        weekendStyle: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.blue[800]),
        holidayStyle: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.blue[800]),
      ),
      daysOfWeekStyle: DaysOfWeekStyle(
        weekendStyle: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.blue[600]),
      ),
      headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
        centerHeaderTitle: true,
        formatButtonVisible: false,
      ),
      builders: CalendarBuilders(
        selectedDayBuilder: (context, date, _) {
          return FadeTransition(
            opacity: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_animationController),
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue[300],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(36.0),
                  border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.blue[300])),
              child: Text(
                '${date.day}',
                style: TextStyle().copyWith(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        todayDayBuilder: (context, date, _) {
          return Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(36.0),
                border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.white)),
            child: Text(
              '${date.day}',
              style: TextStyle().copyWith(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          );
        },
        markersBuilder: (context, date, events, holidays) {
          final children = <Widget>[];

          if (events.isNotEmpty) {
            children.add(
              Positioned(
                child: _buildEventsMarker(date, events),
              ),
            );
          }

          if (holidays.isNotEmpty) {
            children.add(
              Positioned(
                right: -2,
                top: -2,
                child: _buildHolidaysMarker(),
              ),
            );
          }

          return children;
        },
      ),
      onVisibleDaysChanged: _onVisibleDaysChanged,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildEventsMarker(DateTime date, List events) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(36.0),
          border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.blue[300])),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildHolidaysMarker() {
    return Icon(
      Icons.add_box,
      size: 20.0,
      color: Colors.blueGrey[800],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildsameMonthEventList() {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(22.0),
          child: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text("Appointments of Current Month",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18)),
            backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[200],
            brightness: Brightness.light,
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
//          backgroundColor: Color(0x44000000),
            elevation: 0.5,
          ),
        ),
        body: (_samemonthevents.length == 0)
            ? Text("No appointment record in current month!",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16))
            : ListView(
                children: _samemonthevents
                    .map((event) => Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(width: 0.8),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                        ),
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 4.0),
                        child: (event is Appointment)
                            ? ListTile(
                                leading: Column(children: <Widget>[
                                  //Show Weekday, Month and day of Appiontment
                                  Text(
                                      DateFormat('EE').format(event.date) +
                                          '  ' +
                                          DateFormat.MMMd().format(event.date),
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(1.0),
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      )),
                                  //Show Start Time of Appointment
                                  Text(DateFormat.jm().format(event.date),
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        height: 1.5,
                                      )),
                                  //Show End Time of Appointment
                                  Text(
                                    DateFormat.jm().format(event.date.add(
                                        Duration(
                                            minutes: event.duration ?? 0))),
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6)),
                                  ),
                                ]), //Text(DateFormat.Hm().format(event.date)),//DateFormat.Hm().format(now)
                                title: Text(event.title),
                                trailing: event.status == 'UNCONFIRMED'
                                    ? Column(children: <Widget>[
                                        //event.status=='CONFIRMED' ?
                                        Icon(Icons.error,
                                            color: Colors.pink,
                                            //size:25.0,
                                            semanticLabel:
                                                'Unconfirmed Appointment'), //:Container(width:0,height:0),
                                        Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                                      ])
                                    : Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {});
                                  Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) =>
                                              AppointmentDetail(event)));
                                },
                              )
                            : null))
                    .toList()));
  }
}
```

**Backend Code:**

AppointmentAPI.java

```
    @GET
    @Path("me/appointments")
    @Secured(UserRole.PATIENT)
    @JSONP(queryParam = "callback")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response listMyAppointments(
            @Context SecurityContext sc,
            @QueryParam("since") String since,
            @QueryParam("until") String until,
            @QueryParam("is_confirmed") Boolean is_confirmed) {

        String uid = sc.getUserPrincipal().getName();
        List<Appointment> results = retrieveUserAppointments(uid, since, until, is_confirmed);

        return Response.ok(results).build();
    }
```

AppointmentMapper.java

```
    List<Appointment> getAppointmentsByUserId(
            @Param("uid")  String uid,
            @Param("since")  String since,
            @Param("until")  String until,
            @Param("status") AppointmentStatus status);
```

AppointmentMapper.xml

```
<mapper namespace="com.sec.db.AppointmentMapper">
    <select id="getAppointmentById" parameterType="String" resultType="com.sec.entity.Appointment">
        SELECT * FROM Appointment WHERE id= #{id}
    </select>

    <select id="getAppointmentsByUserId" resultType="com.sec.entity.Appointment">
        SELECT *
        FROM Appointment
        WHERE uid= #{uid}
        <choose>
            <when test="since != null and until != null">
                AND date BETWEEN #{since} AND #{until}
            </when>
            <when test="since != null and until == null">
                AND date > #{since}
            </when>
            <when test="since == null and until != null">
                <![CDATA[
                AND date < #{until}
                ]]>
            </when>
        </choose>
        <choose>
            <when test="status == null">
                AND status != 'CANCELLED'
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                AND status = #{status}
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
    </select>
```

**Json Response Example:**

````
### Response

    Status: 200 OK

```JSON
[
  {
    "date": "2020-06-22T14:15:00Z",
    "date_change": "2018-05-14T10:17:40Z",
    "date_create": "2018-05-14T10:17:40Z",
    "detail": "Inflisaport Insertion",
    "duration": 15,
    "id": "2",
    "note": "Looking forward to see you! Take care",
    "status": "CONFIRMED",
    "title": "Private Hospital",
    "uid": "1"
  }
]
````

Comment: need full json response to reproduce this error. please post your full json string. thanks.

Comment: Sure! But there is no error, getSameMonthAppointments in this case basically just performed as getAppointments, which fetch all records from the database and doesn't take any date input from _onVisibleDaysChanged function. The getSameMonthAppointments in this case is just named for thought yet.

Comment: Json Response example has been updated!

Comment: The main issue is that I don't now how to fetch the first date of each month to represent the month correspondingly by '_onVisibleDaysChanged' function. if I can gain that, I could select expected data in database using:    
SELECT *
        FROM Appointment
        WHERE uid= #{uid}
        AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(#{date})
        AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(#{date})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: You can use a variable `current` to control current year/month 
Step 2: You can in `_onVisibleDaysChanged`, call `setState` and set `current` 
Step 3: In `_buildsameMonthEventList`, do filter with every events year/month with  `current's` year/month

code snippet

```
DateTime current = DateTime.now();
...
void _onVisibleDaysChanged(
      DateTime first, DateTime last, CalendarFormat format) {
    setState(() {
      current = first;
    });
    print('CALLBACK: _onVisibleDaysChanged first ${first.toIso8601String()}');
  }
...  
 Widget _buildsameMonthEventList() {
    var _samemontheventsFilter = _samemonthevents.where((element) =>
        element.date.year == current.year &&
        element.date.month == current.month);

    return Scaffold(
        ...
        body: (_samemontheventsFilter.length == 0)
            ? Text("No appointment record in current month!",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16))
            : ListView(
                children: _samemontheventsFilter
                    .map((event) => Container(
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

List<Appointment> appointmentFromJson(String str) => List<Appointment>.from(
    json.decode(str).map((x) => Appointment.fromJson(x)));

String appointmentToJson(List<Appointment> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Appointment {
  Appointment({
    this.date,
    this.dateChange,
    this.dateCreate,
    this.detail,
    this.duration,
    this.id,
    this.note,
    this.status,
    this.title,
    this.uid,
  });

  DateTime date;
  DateTime dateChange;
  DateTime dateCreate;
  String detail;
  int duration;
  String id;
  String note;
  String status;
  String title;
  String uid;

  factory Appointment.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Appointment(
        date: DateTime.parse(json["date"]),
        dateChange: DateTime.parse(json["date_change"]),
        dateCreate: DateTime.parse(json["date_create"]),
        detail: json["detail"],
        duration: json["duration"],
        id: json["id"],
        note: json["note"],
        status: json["status"],
        title: json["title"],
        uid: json["uid"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "date": date.toIso8601String(),
        "date_change": dateChange.toIso8601String(),
        "date_create": dateCreate.toIso8601String(),
        "detail": detail,
        "duration": duration,
        "id": id,
        "note": note,
        "status": status,
        "title": title,
        "uid": uid,
      };
}

class Appointments extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppointmentsState createState() => _AppointmentsState();
}

class _AppointmentsState extends State<Appointments>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  var _calendarController;
  Map<DateTime, List> _events;
  List<Appointment> _samemonthevents = List<Appointment>();
  AnimationController _animationController;
  DateTime current = DateTime.now();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _events = Map<DateTime, List>();
    _calendarController = CalendarController();

    getSameMonthAppointments();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    );
    _animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _calendarController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  getSameMonthAppointments() async {
    String jsonString = '''
    [
  {
    "date": "2020-09-01T11:15:00Z",
    "date_change": "2018-05-14T10:17:40Z",
    "date_create": "2018-05-14T10:17:40Z",
    "detail": "Inflisaport Insertion",
    "duration": 15,
    "id": "2",
    "note": "Looking forward to see you! Take care",
    "status": "CONFIRMED",
    "title": "Private Hospital",
    "uid": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-09-22T01:15:00Z",
    "date_change": "2018-05-14T10:17:40Z",
    "date_create": "2018-05-14T10:17:40Z",
    "detail": "Inflisaport Insertion",
    "duration": 15,
    "id": "2",
    "note": "Looking forward to see you! Take care",
    "status": "CONFIRMED",
    "title": "Private Hospital",
    "uid": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-10-01T07:15:00Z",
    "date_change": "2018-05-14T10:17:40Z",
    "date_create": "2018-05-14T10:17:40Z",
    "detail": "Inflisaport Insertion",
    "duration": 15,
    "id": "2",
    "note": "Looking forward to see you! Take care",
    "status": "CONFIRMED",
    "title": "Private Hospital",
    "uid": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-10-22T09:15:00Z",
    "date_change": "2018-05-14T10:17:40Z",
    "date_create": "2018-05-14T10:17:40Z",
    "detail": "Inflisaport Insertion",
    "duration": 15,
    "id": "2",
    "note": "Looking forward to see you! Take care",
    "status": "CONFIRMED",
    "title": "Private Hospital",
    "uid": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-10-30T10:15:00Z",
    "date_change": "2018-05-14T10:17:40Z",
    "date_create": "2018-05-14T10:17:40Z",
    "detail": "Inflisaport Insertion",
    "duration": 15,
    "id": "2",
    "note": "Looking forward to see you! Take care",
    "status": "CONFIRMED",
    "title": "Private Hospital",
    "uid": "1"
  }
]
    ''';

    http.Response response = http.Response(jsonString, 200);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      _samemonthevents = appointmentFromJson(response.body);
    }
  }

  void _onVisibleDaysChanged(
      DateTime first, DateTime last, CalendarFormat format) {
    setState(() {
      current = first;
    });
    print('CALLBACK: _onVisibleDaysChanged first ${first.toIso8601String()}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(60.0),
          child: AppBar(
            leading: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                color: Colors.black,
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {});
                  /* Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainPage()));*/
                }),
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text("Appointment", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            brightness: Brightness.light,
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
//          backgroundColor: Color(0x44000000),
            elevation: 0.5,
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                color: Colors.black,
                icon: Icon(Icons.list),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {});
                  /* Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => AppointmentList()));*/
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Column(children: <Widget>[
            _buildTableCalendarWithBuilders(),
            const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            //_buildEventList()
            //_buildsameMonthEventList()
            Expanded(child: _buildsameMonthEventList()),
          ]);
        }));
  }

  // More advanced TableCalendar configuration (using Builders & Styles)
  Widget _buildTableCalendarWithBuilders() {
    return TableCalendar(
      calendarController: _calendarController,
      events: _events,
      //holidays: _holidays,
      initialCalendarFormat: CalendarFormat.month,
      formatAnimation: FormatAnimation.slide,
      startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.sunday,
      availableGestures: AvailableGestures.all,
      availableCalendarFormats: const {CalendarFormat.month: ''},
      calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
        outsideDaysVisible: false,
        weekendStyle: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.blue[800]),
        holidayStyle: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.blue[800]),
      ),
      daysOfWeekStyle: DaysOfWeekStyle(
        weekendStyle: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.blue[600]),
      ),
      headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
        centerHeaderTitle: true,
        formatButtonVisible: false,
      ),
      builders: CalendarBuilders(
        selectedDayBuilder: (context, date, _) {
          return FadeTransition(
            opacity: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_animationController),
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue[300],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(36.0),
                  border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.blue[300])),
              child: Text(
                '${date.day}',
                style: TextStyle().copyWith(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        todayDayBuilder: (context, date, _) {
          return Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(36.0),
                border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.white)),
            child: Text(
              '${date.day}',
              style: TextStyle().copyWith(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          );
        },
        markersBuilder: (context, date, events, holidays) {
          final children = <Widget>[];

          if (events.isNotEmpty) {
            children.add(
              Positioned(
                child: _buildEventsMarker(date, events),
              ),
            );
          }

          if (holidays.isNotEmpty) {
            children.add(
              Positioned(
                right: -2,
                top: -2,
                child: _buildHolidaysMarker(),
              ),
            );
          }

          return children;
        },
      ),
      onVisibleDaysChanged: _onVisibleDaysChanged,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildEventsMarker(DateTime date, List events) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(36.0),
          border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.blue[300])),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildHolidaysMarker() {
    return Icon(
      Icons.add_box,
      size: 20.0,
      color: Colors.blueGrey[800],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildsameMonthEventList() {
    var _samemontheventsFilter = _samemonthevents.where((element) =>
        element.date.year == current.year &&
        element.date.month == current.month);

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(22.0),
          child: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text("Appointments of Current Month",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18)),
            backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[200],
            brightness: Brightness.light,
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
//          backgroundColor: Color(0x44000000),
            elevation: 0.5,
          ),
        ),
        body: (_samemontheventsFilter.length == 0)
            ? Text("No appointment record in current month!",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16))
            : ListView(
                children: _samemontheventsFilter
                    .map((event) => Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(width: 0.8),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                        ),
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 4.0),
                        child: (event is Appointment)
                            ? ListTile(
                                leading: SizedBox(
                                  width: 90,
                                  child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                                    //Show Weekday, Month and day of Appiontment
                                    Text(
                                        DateFormat('EE').format(event.date) +
                                            '  ' +
                                            DateFormat.MMMd().format(event.date),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(1.0),
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        )),
                                    //Show Start Time of Appointment
                                    Text(DateFormat.jm().format(event.date),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          height: 1.5,
                                        )),
                                    //Show End Time of Appointment
                                    Text(
                                      DateFormat.jm().format(event.date.add(
                                          Duration(
                                              minutes: event.duration ?? 0))),
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6)),
                                    ),
                                  ]),
                                ), //Text(DateFormat.Hm().format(event.date)),//DateFormat.Hm().format(now)
                                title: Text(event.title),
                                trailing: event.status == 'UNCONFIRMED'
                                    ? Column(children: <Widget>[
                                        //event.status=='CONFIRMED' ?
                                        Icon(Icons.error,
                                            color: Colors.pink,
                                            //size:25.0,
                                            semanticLabel:
                                                'Unconfirmed Appointment'), //:Container(width:0,height:0),
                                        Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                                      ])
                                    : Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {});
                                  /* Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) =>
                                AppointmentDetail(event)));*/
                                },
                              )
                            : null))
                    .toList()));
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Appointments(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There is also a little issue that I noticed, that 'Private Hospital' isn't centered... Is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: DateTime format issue. use SizedBox to force a static width     ListTile(
                                leading: SizedBox(
                                  width: 90,
                                  child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                                    //Show Weekday, Month and day of Appiontment
                                    Text(

Comment: Oh my god! You are so efficient!!! If you have any interest, please do have a look over my new question! Many thanks again! Link below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64415647/anyway-to-enable-remember-me-function-using-sharedpreferences-in-flutter

Comment: This solution is so elegant! 0 error, great work! Words could barely express my gratitude to you, savior of the day!

Comment: Well, It seems there is an error. As you may notice, in the original demo, those date with appointment will marked with a blue circle, which is based on the _buildEventsMarker. Now, since the input has been modified to the first date of each month, this function turns to be invalid.

Comment: To fix this, just add the original part back then it will work as expected! Wonderful!

Comment: I just posted a new question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64435599/how-to-produce-a-list-of-30-days-date-in-flutter) about making an upcoming 30 days list of appointment related to this calendar! I saw you answer before in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57422219/dart-flutter-list-of-days-in-a-date-range) and tried your solution. Can you please help me with this? Much appreciated!

Comment: Now event is replased with eventloader. can you please same code with updated version of this library sir.

Comment: Hello sir, can you please share same demo with updated library . i will very thankful to you.