# How to retrieve a list of days from a date range || Flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, flutter-layout

i want to take duration in months how to i take
This is my code

```dart
labelText: 'End Date',
 hintText: ' yyyy-MM-dd'),
 onTap: () async {
  final int dur = int.parse(durationController.text);

  var stDate = DateTime.parse(startDateController.text);

  final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
  final String formatted = formatter.format(stDate);
  final double days = 31;
  final int day = days.toInt();
  print(formatted);
  DateTime thirtyDaysFromNow =
      stDate.add(new Duration(days: dur * day - 7));
  print('thirty days $thirtyDaysFromNow');
  DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
    context: context,
    initialDate: DateTime.now(),
    firstDate: DateTime(1991),
    lastDate: DateTime(2101),
  ).then((pickedDate) {
    if (pickedDate != null) {
      String formattedDate =
          DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(pickedDate);

      print(formattedDate);

      setState(() {
        endDateController.text = formatter.format(
            DateTime.parse(thirtyDaysFromNow.toString()));
      });
      print(endDateController.text);
    } else {
      print("Date is not selected");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: [Read this thread on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57422219/10910438)

Comment: how to add months  when i selected start date automatically comes end date

Comment: can you please what you want to do in very easy way?
like what is the userstory here ? what user what to do and what you want to do ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dart/Flutter : List of days in a date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57422219/dart-flutter-list-of-days-in-a-date-range)

Comment: i want to when i select start date the end date automatically comes using months like 12, 24, 36, 48 in flutter .